# Unhandled Promises Rejection when I move through my react native app

Tags: react-native

This error occurs when I move through my app and also sometimes all the icons and fonts doesn't load properly.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory for
>   /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%40anonymous%2FXcelerate-11f769e1-4902-43b1-b0e1-977c3d44d1fc/ExponentAsset-744ce60078c17d86006dd0edabcd59a7.ttf
>   doesn't exist.]
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:155:41
>   in createErrorFromErrorData
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:104:55
>   in 
>   - ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has do something with the `fonts`. 
The font TTF file is not found and it is being loaded in async which is causing the issue.

Comment: So what to do now?

Comment: What expo version do you use?

Comment: I am using expo version 34.0.1